# Restrict Database Query to Single Entity

Tags: hibernate, select, spring-data-jpa

I have below entity classes:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Entity1 {

//other variables

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private String id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "entity1")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Entity2 entity2;

}
```

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Entity2 {

//other variables

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    @MapsId
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Entity1 entity1;

}
```

I am using `Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);` from `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` interface to query the database.

Now I want to fetch data only from table associated with Entity1 and not from Entity2.
But findAll() is fetching data from both the tables.
Also I do not want to use @Query.

Can anyone please suggest how I can update my code to fetch data only from Entity1 table given that I need to store and update the data on both tables using save() method.

Let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [bidirectional @OneToOne association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy). So, as it suggested in the documentation:

> Although you might annotate the parent-side association to be fetched lazily, Hibernate cannot honor this request since it cannot know whether the association is `null` or not.
>
> The only way to figure out whether there is an associated record on the child side is to fetch the child association using a secondary query. *Because this can lead to N+1 query issues, it’s much more efficient to use unidirectional `@OneToOne` associations with the `@MapsId` annotation in place.*
>
> However, *if you really need to use a bidirectional association and want to make sure that this is always going to be fetched lazily, then you need to enable lazy state initialization bytecode enhancement and use the `@LazyToOne` annotation as well.*

Comment: Thanks, I needed to keep bidirectional One-One mapping so used @LazyToOne as suggested.
I also used Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement to make it work.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html#_gradle_plugin